Linux showing wrong hard drive size after failed dd clone
I was attempting to system clone a BTRFS filesystem from a set of 4TB drives in RAID1 BTRFS to a set of 12TB drives in RAID1 BTRFS using instructions from here:
How to copy a btrfs filesystem
I used the dd method to perform the clone.
For one of the drives, I stopped dd midway through the process and I believe it corrupted something about the drive's filesystem.  The drive should have 12TB/10.91TiB as the other drive shows, yet it shows as having only 62.75GiB, roughly where I stopped the transfer.  Further attempts are unsuccessful because the drive thinks it is only ~62GB large and complain that it can't finish transferring because the drive is "out of space".  This seems to be some kind of problem with the partition table so I tried to remove and recreate it at the correct size using these instructions:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1075794/why-linux-dd-is-erroring-with-no-space-left-on-device-while-copying-a-single
and
Live resize of a GPT partition on Linux
However, even after refreshing my system with

sudo partprobe /dev/sdd

gparted and my system all think the drive is still 62GB.
Oddly, lsblk shows the disk as its proper size so clearly it is capable of knowing the correct size of the drives attached to it.
How would I get linux to realize that this drive is actually a 12TB drive and not a 62GB one?


Remove all partitions, making the drive entirely unallocated (free) space. Confirm that action has succeeded. 2. Create partitions as desired. 3. Format the partitions.


I am able to see the drive reports as being partitionless in gparted and I have cleared it using gparted and fdisk.  I think the issue is in the underlying partition table somehow where it is confused about the size of the drive.  I am starting from a partitionless drive and using dd to clone the btrfs partition from the other drive.

Please [edit] the question and copy&paste the exact commands you used to clone the drive and all the commands you use for checking with their corresponding output. (Instead of describing the commands, output, error messages in your own words.)

The issue is, "using dd to clone the btrfs partition from the other drive." They're different sizes. Instead, create a partition, format it BTRFS, then transfer data.

I ended up fixing this problem by restarting the computer.  Not sure why no other solution worked.
After turning on the computer again, I plugged in the problematic drive and it was recognized as the correct size and data could be copied to it.
Sometimes the solution is just to turn it off and turn it on again.
